# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. in application server

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server-2012

we have a medium share point farm , recently in application servers i found below errors in event viewer.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          6/10/2015 2:00:08 PM
Event ID:      5586
Task Category: Database
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          XYZ\mc-sps3e-pool
Computer:      APP01.xyz.local
Description:
Unknown SQL Exception 18452 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation" Guid="{6FB7E0CD-52E7-47DD-997A-241563931FC2}" />
    <EventID>5586</EventID>
    <Version>14</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-06-10T11:00:08.520279400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>206687</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4128" ThreadID="811588" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>APP01.xyz.local</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1537596049-1164153464-4201862467-47317" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="int0">18452</Data>
    <Data Name="string1">Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

--

and in sql server

```
    Log Name:      Application
Source:        MSSQL$XYZSPMC
Date:          6/10/2015 2:10:19 PM
Event ID:      17806
Task Category: Logon
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SQL1.xyz..local
Description:
SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure. The logon attempt failed   [CLIENT: 10.xxx.0.98]
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="MSSQL$XYZSPMC" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">17806</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>4</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-06-10T11:10:19.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>39127406</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>SQL1.xyz..local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>8009030c</Data>
    <Data>14</Data>
    <Data>AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure.</Data>
    <Data>The logon attempt failed </Data>
    <Data> [CLIENT: 10.xxx.0.98]</Data>
    <Binary>8E4500001400000011000000530051004C005000530050004D0043005C004D004F004A00530050004D004300000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: are you using the Kerbros authentication? did you see any problem with farm?

Answer (score 1):

Check password for this user XYZ\mc-sps3e-pool, maybe it was expired or changed.
Also check if your AD is up and running.